# How to apply scroll animations to grid view control

Tags: c#

whenever new row is added then already existing row will be slowly move downword and new one will be added in the grid view control.

Comment: You have asked the same question 3 times today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the jQuery.ScrollTo plugin it works great for scrolling the screen slowly.
Have some control below your grid it can be an existing control or you could add an anchor tag like

After you add your row you would add the script $.scrollTo('#grid_bottom') using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript or ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript (use the script manager one of you are using an update panel) and it should scroll down slowly.

[Link to download page for jQuery ScrollTo Plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Here is some example code, you can change the duration in the ScrollTo function or leave it off, and the scroll will happen immediately without smoothly scrolling:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Items
    {
        get { return (List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)ViewState["Items"]; }
        set { ViewState["Items"] = value; }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Items = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(i.ToString(), "Test" + i));

            GridTest.DataSource = Items;
            GridTest.DataBind();

        }
    }



    protected void cmdAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", DateTime.Now.ToString()));

        GridTest.DataSource = Items;
        GridTest.DataBind();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "scrollto",
                string.Format(
                    @" $(document).ready(function(){{
                        $.scrollTo($('#{0}'), 2000);
                }});", cmdAddNew.ClientID), true);

    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="/JavaScript/jquery.scrollTo-min.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlTest">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdAddNew2" runat="server" OnClick="cmdAddNew_Click">Add New</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdAddNew" runat="server" OnClick="cmdAddNew_Click">Add New</asp:LinkButton>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi,By using java script is it possible or not?

Comment: give me the sample code to scroll the grid view rows using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Comment: I have to put $.ScrollTo('#sc1');  <div id="sc1" runat="server"><asp:Gridview id="gridview1" runat="server"></asp:gridview></div> but it is not working.

Comment: How dynamically move down the rows of the griview control when ever new row will be added with out scroll bars.

Comment: I added a code sample.  If you are in a situation where you are having something longer than a page, you are going to have scrollbars unless you set the overflow to hidden and then you are just not going to see the extra.  You could put your table in a fixed height div, and set the overflow to auto and that would allow the table to scroll and not the page.  The scrollTo thing should still work I think.